# Allow users to upload files to a Google Drive service account

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I need to let others to upload files to my Google Drive SERVICE ACCOUNT (with Javascript)

I want to let users (that dont need to have Google accounts) of my web app to upload files to a service account I created.

The "quickstart" demo of Google documentation works but only to authorize the users to use their own accounts.

Just in case I have the api key, service account key (json) and client id.

I saw other similar questions in stackoverflow but it seems that all have incomplete answers.

Can anybody show me a working sample to achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It will nonetheless be a high risk to let anybody upload files on your account (spam, ddos, etc.)

Comment: it seems that google in not in the business for providing a free service through a single account. you can't create an app that provides a service that acts as an individual. seems like you're doing something beyond the scope of your own user account.

Comment: I dont think is impossible, I did it before but with VB net and Drive V2. Besides, there was (I cant see it now) a limit in Google Developer Console that showed "1000 request/day/user" or something like that, so I guess that ddos or spam is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code TestGoogleDrive.json - your service account key.

```
var { google } = require('googleapis');
var key = require('./TestGoogleDrive.json');

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    ],
   null
  );

var drive = google.drive( 'v3');


jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
   }
  // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
  drive.files.list({
      auth: jwtClient,
      pageSize: 10,
      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
    }, function (err, resp) {
    resp.data.files.map(file => console.log(file));
  });

});
```

Full information you can find following [link](https://medium.com/@abhimanyuPathania/google-drive-service-accounts-and-nodejs-a038b8ec482f).

Comment: Thank you Vladimir I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: Awesome Vladimir, finally I did it but it was necessary to change some things because I got "auth of undefined" error, I changed the first lines for: `const google = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');
const key = require('./mi_archivo.json');
const drive = google.drive('v3');
const jwtClient...` according to you sample and your source. Thanks again.